# Captura de evento del mouse, con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Lo que busco es hacer que mi `div` de `class="insedeMuve"` (la bolita azul) se mueva junto al cursor, cuando este llegue a su div padre.** Ya he logrado este efecto en un `div`, hijo directo de `body`; pero *en este caso intento aplicarle el mismo javascript al nieto del `body`* y no funciona.

```js
let insideMove = document.querySelector('.insideMove');
let etiqueta = document.querySelector('.etiqueta');
etiqueta.addEventListener("mouseover", mover);
function mover(){
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", inside);
    function inside(e){
    insideMove.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
    insideMove.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
    };
};
```

```css
.box {
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
    border: solid 2px green;
}
.etiqueta {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    border: solid 2px yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 400px;
}
.insideMove {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height:16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
    <div class="bol">
        <div class="box">
        <div class="etiqueta">
            <div class="insideMove"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Yo supongo que necesito que el cursor detecte que llego al `div` padre de la "bolita azul" y luego empieza moverse junto a la "bolita azul", pero no sé cómo hacer eso.

Comment: Tienes un par de errores, `document.querySelector('.insideMove');` la clase correcta es `insideMuve` y, además, cuando asignas eventos con `.addEventListener()`, no debe llevar el `on`, pero el evento debería ser `mousemove` en lugar de `mouseenter`. Con eso, solo faltaría limitar el movimiento al área del padre.

Comment: acabo de corregir esos errores y le  agregue código javascript, ahora mi problema es que el cursor y el div de clase " .insideMuve" logran moverse coordinadamente; pero no están juntos.

Comment: No entiendo, lo que quieres es que se mueva al lado del cursor o solo dentro del cuadro hijo.

Comment: @CarlosAriasMontero quiero que se mueva "la bolita azul" junto al cursor, dentro del cuadro hijo.

Answer (score 1):

Por fin lo logre!!! Talvez se puede reducir a algo más simple, pero es lo tengo, por ahora. **con esto se puede hacer el efecto del mouse sobre los botones en:**
[https://rockyvision.com/fr][1]

```js
let hijo = document.querySelector('.hijo');
let etiqueta = document.querySelectorAll('.etiqueta');
//El metodo .getBoundingClientRect() nos da 
//la posicion de un elemento con respecto al viewport(en numeros).
// tomare la posicion constante del elemento .hijo 
const coords = hijo.getBoundingClientRect();
const j = coords.top; // estamos obteniendo la posicion top en numero
const k = coords.left;

// se aplica forEach para obtener posicion de cada movimiento del mouse
etiqueta.forEach(link => {
// se obtiene la posicion del mouse con la funcion  mover(e)
    function mover(e){
// se calcula la posicion top y left del mouse al cual le restamos
// la posicion del elemento "hijo"; resultado: mouse e "hijo" juntos 
     let m = e.pageY ;
     let n = e.pageX ;

     let t = m - j;
     let l = n - k;
     hijo.style.top = t + "px"; // agregando px a los numeros
     hijo.style.left = l + "px";
    };
// mouseover dice que entro en elemento etiqueta
    link.addEventListener("mouseover",() => {
    hijo.classList.add("edd1");// solo agrega un class que le da color red

     window.addEventListener("mousemove",mover);// agrega el evento junto a la funcion 
    });

    link.addEventListener("mouseleave",() => {// mouseleave dice que salio del elemento etiqueta
    hijo.classList.remove("edd1"); // le quita un class, que le quita color red
     window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mover);// remuev el evento
    });
});
```

```css
/* Simples estilos para delimitar los div*/
.box{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: solid 1px black;
}
.etiqueta{
width:100px;
height:100px;
position: absolute;
left:50px;
top:50px;
background: green;
overflow: hidden;
position:relative;
}
.hijo{
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: blue;
transform: scale(0); /*desaparece el elemento hijo*/
}
.edd1{
background-color: red;
transform: scale(1); /*reaparece el elemento hijo con el mause al centro*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="etiqueta">
  <div class="hijo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```